# Java Calendar with timeZone behavior

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, timezone

How can I work with the Calendar within the timezone? For me the results, I got, are confusing.
Can you please explain, the results, that I got?

**The first case**:

The *date* is "2021-05-07T23:33:11.000Z", *timeZone* equals to "Europe/Berlin", running with `-Duser.timezone=UTC`

Evaluating
`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(date); cal.setTimeZone(timeZone); cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); cal.getTime()`

Gives `2021-05-01T21:33:11.000Z` (not expected), but i expected to get `2021-05-01T23:33:11.000Z + 02:00`

Evaluating
`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(date); cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); cal.getTime()`

Gives `2021-05-01T23:33:11.000Z`, as expected

So, seems that, when we specify the timeZone, Calendar calculates the date in UTC in such way, that `Calendar.getTime() - Timezone.getOffset()`, but not `Calendar.getTime() + Timezone.getOffset()` It means, that when we specify the time via `.setTime(millis)` and timeZone via `setTimeZone(timezone)`. Calendar interprets millis (from *date*) like it is already within provided timeZone, but not in UTC. Right?

**The second case**:

The *date* is "2021-05-07T23:33:11.000Z", *timeZone* is "Europe/Berlin", running with `-Duser.timezone=UTC`. the *date* is FRIDAY in UTC (the same as the first case)

`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(date); cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`

Gives us 6, that is FRIDAY, as expected

`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(date); cal.setTimeZone(timeZone); cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`

Gives us 7, that is SATURDAY (not expected), but we expected to get FRIDAY due to results in **the first case**.

Comment: I recommend you neither use the `Calendar` nor the `TimeZone` class. Both are poorly designed and confusing as you have seen, and both are long outdated. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html

Comment: How are you examining those Date values?  If you’re converting them to ISO 8601 format using a DateFormat, be aware that DateFormat has its own [setTimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) method (which is another good reason to use the java.time package and avoid that confusion).